# iPhone web application developed using ASP.Net

Tags: iphone

We are developing an ASP.Net web application and need that application to work properly on iPhone

1. Are there any  memory constraints for an ASP.Net web application  to work properly on iPhone
2. are there any issues with  usage of ASP.net controls like gridview/ tab view etc.
3. would there be any issues with 3rd party controls like Ajax RADSchduler from Telerik
4. any other other constraints for a web application to work on iPhone.

Thnx
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If we are talking about a standard asp.net website, memory constraints aren't really the issue. Asp.net just generates (ugly) html with some javascript. Nothing really special about that. Memory in this setup is important server-side. Offcours asp.net tends to generate lots of bloat when viewstate is enabled (without it, too). And this IS an issue when it comes to bandwidth, especially for mobile applications.
2. When using the Asp.net Ajax Toolkit, it should work [crossbrowser](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/BrowserCompatibilityForASPNETAjax.aspx). Apple Safari version 2.0 or later versions are supported.
3. Checkout the docs for the 3rd party controls, which browsers are supported. If Safari is supported, it should work.
4. But i would suggest using [asp.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/whatisaspmvc/) instead of standard asp.net controls, because it allows full control over html and javascript. This will ensure minimum use of bandwith and maximum javascript performance. Or any other language/framework with full control like [php](https://www.php.net/tut.php)/[codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/) or [python](http://www.python.org/)/[django](http://www.djangoproject.com/). And maybe a javascript library like [mootools](http://mootools.net/), [jquery](http://jquery.com/) or [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I think having a real iPhone to test on would be most optimal.

As for integrating third-party components you should be able to ask the vendor about their support. These Telerisk and Infrastigistic components look great, but you need to ask yourself do you need that amount of power and options, if you follow the mantra of the iPhone and Apple in general you'll want to keep it as simple as possible.

One approach is to develop a different view for the iPhone, keeping the display basic and optimized to the dimensions of the screen and the touch system rather than cursor.

Since Safari is based on Webkit you can get some basic compatibility testing on your local PC.